# How to convert a json dump array dump to javascript array object

Tags: javascript, json

the json string is:

`x = "['test', 'test1', 'test2']"`

I used:

```
y = JSON.parse(x);
```

When i get the first element:

```
alert(y[0]);
```

The result is:

> [

How can I change the above json string to a Javascript array object?

Comment: That's not JSON. Strings in JSON are delimited by double quotes not single quotes.

Comment: Fix whatever is trying to serve that broken JSON and then you can use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: wrong json with ' character. try use " as
var x = "[\"test\",\"test1\", \"test2\"]"; or var x = '["test", "test1", "test2"]';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way around with quotes.
i.e x should be

```
x = '["test", "test1", "test2"]'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem by using the following code

```
const alert_message = x.split(',').map(d=> d.replace(/\[|\]|\'|\'/g, ''));
```